# How to do localisation of dynamic string in android

Tags: java, android

I have a string  `<string name="time_required">%1$s %2$s</string>`
here %1$s is a number(example: 14) and %2$s is a string. My localisation is working properly for all other type of string resources, but the dynamic strings which contain string values like "abc", "aabc" or any strings, these are not converted into my desired language. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic string values will not be converted in locale string.

Generally what you can do if dynamic strings are coming from server:

1. You can pass device locale in header when you call API (e.g. EN)
2. Server will response in requested language
3. Your app will display that language.

For most cases, dynamic strings values have to come from server pre locallized.

Comment: These dynamic strings are not coming from server, its like based on the condition string will be minutes, hours or days etc. That's why I used dynamic strings. But it's localisation is not occuring

Comment: Have you added those strings' localized version in appropriate strings.xml files?

Comment: yes , I have checked . Those are in appropriate strings.xml files